# SED - how to add ' ' and , to every character of a string

Tags: shell, sed

I've been trying to add some special characters to a list of strings, but I'm stuck with sed, see if anyone has any idea:

```
[user@user]$ more file.txt
STRING#!-@


[user@user]$ cat file.txt | sed -r 's/(.{1})/\1'\'\''\, /g;s/,$//'
S'', T'', R'', I'', N'', G'', #'', !'', -'', @'',
```

I would need the two ' ' between the characters and the comma after each character 'S',
The correct output should be something like this:
'S', 'T', 'R', 'I', 'N', 'G', '#', '!', '-', '@',

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you understand what `/\1'\'\''\, /` does? What do you think `\1` means? What do these `'\''` mean?

Comment: \1 would be to print out the string and the '\' to print the special character ' ?

Comment: ```echo '1234' | sed "s/./'&',/g;s/,$//"```

Comment: What should happen if your string contains `foo'bar`? For most data formats you'd need some kind of escaping like `'\'',` there instead of `''',`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Corrected version: `sed -r 's/(.{1})/'\''\1'\'',/g;s/,$//'` - the backreference should be between the quotes. Not sure whether you need the space after comma or not, I deleted it to allow the second `s` command to match.

You can also use `\x27` to represent single quote character:

```sh
$ echo 'STRING#!-@' | sed 's/./\x27&\x27,/g; s/,$//'
'S','T','R','I','N','G','#','!','-','@'
```

`&` will have entire text matched by the regexp, so no need to use capture groups for this case.

Other notes:

- No need to use `cat file | sed '..'`, you can use `sed '..' file`
- `-E` is more portable these days compared to `-r`
- `.{1}` is same as `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`, too:

```
awk '{
  split($0, chars, ""); 
  joined = "\x27";
  for (i=1; i in chars; i++) {
    joined = joined sep chars[i];
    sep = "\x27,\x27"
  };
  print joined"\x27"
}' file.txt
```

One-liner:

```sh
awk '{split($0,chars,"");joined="\x27";for (i=1;i in chars;i++) {joined=joined sep chars[i];sep="\x27,\x27"};print joined"\x27"}' file.txt
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/h2CdhP).

NOTES:

- `split($0, chars, "")` splits the input string into chars
- `joined = "\x27"` - initializes `joined` with a `'` char
- `sep = ""` initialized `sep` with an empty string
- `for (i=1; i in chars; i++) { joined = joined sep chars[i]; sep = "\x27,\x27" }` joins the chars with `','` substring and adds these to `joined`
- `print joined"\x27"` - prints `joined` with a `'` appended to it.